# how do On/Off light in angular?

Tags: angular, frontend, backend, light

I have a list of users and I need to create badge circle(green/red) on each user in angular, for active user there is circle green light , and for inactive user there is circle red light .. thanks

Comment: not clear what you are trying to do. what is `green` and `red`? is it background color of an element? Please add more description that tells clearly you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks yash for replay, I mean for active user there is green circle light , and for inactive user there is red circle light , now I have 'on' 'off' word for each one , I need to make front-end when it is on the circle  light is green , and when it is off the circle light is red

Comment: so you are displaying a list of users and want to show a badge circle(green/red) on each user?

Comment: yes exactly ,,,

Comment: it will be helpful if you add your angular component. for example, how do you save the user on frontend and how the object looks like, etc

Comment: @AsmaAlghamdi  may be you want to apply `ngClass` here. based on the input change the class to `active` and `inactive` ,and  add css for for both `.active` and `.inactive` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can generate the status dynamically:

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users">
        <span class="dot" [ngClass]="{'active': (user.status==='on'), 'inactive':(user.status === 'off')}"></span>
        {{user.name}}
      </li>
```

Here is the working example : [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fpx2is?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you very much programoholic, it's work , the reference is very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Use font awesome. Then use angular directive for setting classes. Something like:

```
  <i class="fas fa-power-off" [class.on]=”isOn” (click)=“onClick()></i>
```

Css

```
 i{color:red;}   i.on{color:green}
```

Typescript

```
  on=false;
  onClick():void{
       this.on=!this.on;
   }
```

Comment: thank you very much jens , I added what you mentioned , I have one question how to integrated to backend , this <td>{{user.active_status}}</td> returns on or off word for each user , how integrated with your code ?

Comment: Do you have a callback method from the server. Whet this.user is set? I’m that method you can add.  this.on=user.active_status. If you need to toggle the value in the server you will need to add a post in the onClick method and remove this.on and only user user.active_status

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you want